# Populate a vector with linearly increased values

Tags: c++, vector

I'd to populate/initialize a vector with linearly increased value. For example, for every element in this vector, I'd like the next one is `a` more than the previous. Or the `kth` element has a value of `k*a`

something like this:

```
float a = 1.132;
vector<float> v(100);

for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
{
    v[n] = n*a;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it? Thanks.

A matlab example would be the `linspace(beginning value, end value, number of points)`

```
linspace(1,5, 6)

ans =

    1.0000    1.8000    2.6000    3.4000    4.2000    5.0000
```

Comment: What do you want to use the vector for? If you use `n*a` instead of the `n`-th vector element you get the same values, so no need for the vector in first place

Comment: For the requirements in the question (using `n * a`) there are simpler ways. If you have more complicated algorithms that doesn't involve the index, or if you really need the values in a vector, then you could possibly use [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

Comment: @user463035818, Maybe some function takes a range of data. Use of some kind of projection mechanism on data is rather common.

Comment: Or maybe a combination of [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing you could do is switch to using `std::generate` or `std::generate_n` instead of a for loop.  The `generate` version could look like

```
int main()
{
    float a = 1.132;
    std::vector<float> v(100);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0, &a]() mutable { return n++ * a; });
}
```

Another option is to create an iterator that will generate the value as you iterate it.  This has the advantage that you do not need to initialize `v` with any default constructed valued (this can be/is expensive).  Then you use the vectors range constructor and it will initialize all of the elements.  As long as the iterator abides by the forward iterator requirements then the vector will figure out the space needed (which if it is not random access causes a full iteration), allocate, and then initialize(full iteration).  This could be expensive with the double iteration so it might not be any faster and could be slower then the generate case (since zero initializing is pretty fast).

Comment: And why exactly would that be preferable to the good old loop I honestly wonder...The loop is shorter and with simpler syntax.  There is absolutely no advantage to using this in place of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to C++11 you can use `std::generate` with a lambda :

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0, &a] () mutable { return a * n++; });
```

However, for this use case a vector is hardly needed as said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a type that has an `operator++` and a conversion to `float`, and use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct spacer
{
    spacer(float scale, int count = 0) : scale(scale), count(count) {}
    spacer operator++(){ ++count; return *this; }
    operator float(){ return count * scale; }
private:
    float scale;
    int count;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> v(100);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), spacer(1.132));
}
```

If you have access to `boost`, you can instantiate your vector using that and [`boost::counting_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

struct spacer
{
    spacer(float scale, int count = 0) : scale(scale), count(count) {}
    spacer operator++(){ ++count; return *this; }
    operator float() const{ return count * scale; }
    bool operator==(const spacer & rhs) const{ return std::tie(count, scale) == std::tie(rhs.count, rhs.scale); }
private:
    float scale;
    int count;
};

int main()
{
    using iter = boost::counting_iterator<spacer, std::forward_iterator_tag, std::ptrdiff_t>;
    std::vector<float> v(iter(spacer(1.132)), iter(spacer(1.132, 100)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something like the matlab linspace, it's not directly available in C++ but it's easy to write a function doing that. Like:

```
std::vector<float> linspace(float start, float end, size_t points)
{
  std::vector<float> res(points);
  float step = (end - start) / (points - 1);
  size_t i = 0;
  for (auto& e : res)
  {
    e = start + step * i++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<float> v = linspace(1, 5, 6);

  for (auto f : v) std::cout << f << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 1.8 2.6 3.4 4.2 5
```