# Setup values of an array within a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I would like to give values to a vector/array within a struct. Something like following. However, following code gives errors, and cannot compile.

```
struct Params
{

    float a = 1.132;
    vector<float> v(100);

    for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
    {
        v[n] = n*a;
    }
};
```

How do I fill `v` with value I'd like to fill, and save `v` in the struct? Thanks.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102504/populate-a-vector-with-linearly-increased-values)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was trying to  put previous one into a struct, and ran into problem, as this post stated. This time is within a struct. Thank you.

Comment: use constructor

Comment: @Jahid I would think so too. Care to post some sample code perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: @NickXTsui You really need to find a C++ book, and read up on what a constructor is. Hard to imagine anything more fundamental to C++. If you've got this far and you don't know what a constructor is you're going about things the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code into a contructor like this:

```
Params() {
    v.resize(100);
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
    {
        v[n] = n * a;
    }
}
```

This way, when you make a `Params`, it is already initialized with your values:

```
Params a;
std::cout << a.v[10] << std::endl;
```

This will print `11.32`, for instance.

Comment: "Put the code into a contructor like this:" Just wondering where is the constructor?

Comment: The constructor is the function of the form `Params() {}`. You can find a detailed explanation here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: what if I want to do a lot of things, then putting a lot of code in the constructor is ugly. Can I define a bunch of functions outside the constructor, then just call those function in the constructor? Where do I put all those functions then? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. You can call any other function in your class from your constructor. You put them in the class like any other function, before or after the constructor (typically the constructors come first and then the other functions).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the code on a constructor (is a good solution). 
If for some reason, you dont want to declare a Constructor you can do the next workaround:

```cpp
struct Params {
    float a = 1.132f;
    std::vector<float> vec {
        [this] {
            std::vector<float> v(100);
            for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n)
            {
                v[n] = n*this->a;
            }
            return v;
        }()
    };
};
```

Lambda function is called on "Params" instantiation.

Also in my humble opinion is better to use a Constructor for clarity.